# Regarding a Class Vs Enums

Tags: java

I was having a query , I have declared a class in which all the methods are static and it is following the utility design pattern that is it is acting like helper class Now can I replcae that class with correspond to enum also , Can I have enum having all the staic methods inside it, if Yes then what other advantages it offers ..!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why and what for: java enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/why-and-what-for-java-enum)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with static method is: they can't be mocked for testing. At least not easily.

Putting the methods in an Enum with a single instance gets you a little closer. I'm not sure if enums can be mocked with the standard libraries, you certainly can't without using reflection.

But if you put your methods in an interface implemented by the enum, and everybody else just using the interface, accepting an instance of that interface via constructor (or setter if you have to) you can mock it as easily as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an `enum` as a utility class. There aren't many advantages to it, however: it boils down to the private constructor, which prevents uncontrolled instantiation. I would prefer sticking to the ordinary class with a private constructor since there's an expectation for an enum to be used for an enumerated type and not as a utility class. If you used enum for a singleton, that would give it only a slight bit more sense.