# Singleton via enum way is lazy initialized?

Tags: java, singleton

This is a very wide-spread enum singleton code:

```
public enum enumClazz{
   INSTANCE
   enumClazz(){
     //do something
   }
}
```

and a bunch of places said it is a lazy initialization. But I am confused after I read Chapter 7 of '[Inside the Java Virtual Machine](http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetype.html)' -- The Lifetime of a Type:

> The Java virtual machine specification gives implementations
>   flexibility in the timing of class and interface loading and linking,
>   but strictly defines the timing of initialization. All implementations
>   must initialize each class or interface on its first active use. The
>   following six situations qualify as active uses:
>
> - A new instance of a class is created (in bytecodes, the execution of a new instruction. Alternatively, via implicit creation,
>     reflection, cloning, or deserialization.)
> - The invocation of a static method declared by a class (in bytecodes, the execution of an invokestatic instruction)
> - **The use or assignment of a static field declared by a class or interface, except for static fields that are final and initialized by
>     a compile-time constant expression (in bytecodes, the execution of a
>     getstatic or putstatic instruction)**
> - The invocation of certain reflective methods in the Java API, such as methods in class Class or in classes in the java.lang.reflect
>     package
> - The initialization of a subclass of a class (Initialization of a class requires prior initialization of its superclass.)
> - The designation of a class as the initial class (with the main()< method) when a Java virtual machine starts up

The third point with bold style clarify that if the field is `static final`, the initialization of the field is happened at compile-time. Likewise, the `INSTANCE` in `enumClazz` is implicitly equal to `public static final` and comply with the third point.

Can someone correct me if my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`enum` instance fields are *not* "initialized by a compile-time constant expression". They 
can't be, because [only `String` and primitive types are possible types for a compile-time constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

That means that the class will be initialized when `INSTANCE` is first accessed (which is exactly the desired effect).

The exception in the bold text above exists, because those constants (`static final` fields initialized with a compile-time constant expression) will effectively be inlined during compilation:

```
class A {
  public static final String FOO = "foo";

  static {
    System.out.println("initializing A");
  }
}

class B {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(A.FOO);
  }
}
```

Executing class `B` in this example will **not** initialize `A` (and will *not* print "initializing A"). And if you look into the bytecode generated for `B` you'll see a string literal with the value "foo" and *no* reference to the class `A`.

Comment: _That means that the class will be initialized when `INSTANCE` is first accessed_. If enum class has `static` method (any - make it `void` and do nothing), this enum class and **all** its instances will be initialized immediately when this `static void` method is called. (!) So, you don't need to access `INSTANCE` to initialize it - call that extra method. Done. It's confusing how this enum way is lazy. It is as lazy as simple eager singleton implementation with final field - you call its `static void` method and final `instance` field gets initialized (lazy on first access?).

Comment: @uvsmtid: I'm unsure what you're trying to say. Yes, obviously calling a method on an enum class will also force it to be initialized, just like calling any method on a class will ensure that that class is initialized.

Comment: Correct. Now if it is another lazy implementation (e.g. double-checked locking), the singleton instance is not initialized until `getInstance()` is called - I can see how it is lazy. I don't see how enum approach is _lazier_ than the simplest eager singleton implementation: in both cases, an instance is initialized on the first use of any other (static) method of the class.

Comment: No one is arguing that this is somehow "lazier" than the other implementation. It's simply yet another way to implement that pattern where the JVM helps with the nasty reliably-initialize-under-multi-threaded-access-but-only-at-most-once problem. Personally I prefer to use singletons implemented via some DI framework over both this or a double-check pattern, but that's not in the scope of this question. This question was about "how is this lazy if the value is a compile time constant" (to which the answer is: it's not a compile time constant).

Comment: Well, the title ls _"Singleton via enum way is lazy initialized?"_ and the content says _"a bunch of places said it is a lazy initialization"_. Other Q&As refer to enum way as lazy. So all this does indicate that it is somehow lazier than something eager. NVM, I simply posted [direct question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64051855/441652).

Answer (score 5):

> The third point with bold style clarify that if the field is 'static final', the initialzation of the field is happened at complie-time

Not exactly - it only applies to "*static fields that are final **and initialized by a compile-time constant expression***":

```
static final String = "abc"; //compile time constant
static final Object = new Object(); //initialised at runtime
```

In your case, the singleton will be initialised when the enum class is loaded, i.e. the first time `enumClazz` is referenced in your code.

So it is effectively lazy, unless of course you have a statement somewhere else in your code that uses the enum.

Comment: class Singleton{public static final instance = new Singleton();...} So, for the generic class way, this 'instance' is lazy initialized?

Comment: Yes it would be lazily initialised the same way.

Comment: A statement like `Class<?> c = EnumClazz.class;` does not trigger the initialization of `EnumClazz`. In fact, it’s rather hard to trigger its initialization without actually using it. It’s worth emphasizing that *loading* and *initialization* are two different things.