# Why is this static variable within class null sometimes?

Tags: java, android

I have this code defined.

```
public class AAA {
    public static final Map<String, String> gList = new HashMap<> {{
        put("xxx", "xxx");
        put ....
    }};
    public static AAA instance;
    public static AAA getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new AAA();
        return instance;
    }

    public String calledFunc(String k) {
        return gList.get(k);    
    }
}

public class BBB {
    ...
    public void callingFunc(String k) {
        AAA.getInstance().calledFunc(k);  // <=  NULL pointer some time
    }
}
```

Is this because memory allocation failure or it will be freed some where. Just don't
understand what wrong in my code. Maybe this is not reliable way to initialize.

Comment: You didn't declare the type of `instance`.

Comment: You need to synchronize the getInstance() method.

Comment: Very good point. It will guarantee only one instance.

Comment: It will also *solve the problem,* by enforcing the necessary memory-model constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing something similar to this a while back for holding data between classes, I eventually went with an [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Try something like this perhaps?

```
public enum AAA {
    INSTANCE;
    public static final Map<String, String> gList = new HashMap<> {{
        put("xxx", "xxx");
        put ....
    }};
    public String calledFunc(String k) {
        return gList.get(k);
    }
}
```

If you did this, you wouldn't really need the function in the Enum since you could just do

```
public class BBB {
    ...
    public void callingFunc(String k) {
        AAA.gList.get(k);  // <=  NULL pointer some time
    }
}
```

Comment: This my pretty confused part in java to use enum. So what could be difference between enum and class? Is the way to do initialize?

Comment: When using an Enum, you only allow one instance to be created, and that's typically done when you start the program. The difference between a class and an Enum is that a class can be instantiated multiple times (xxx = new AAA();) unless you specifically make it so you can only create one instance.

In simple terms, Enums are kind of just a cleaner and easier way to make a single instance of a class that can be used to share data, information and even methods across other classes. (That's from my understanding, but I could be wrong at some parts)

Comment: Thanks for explain. There could be more but this is the most important idea to know.

Comment: Here's something you can look at; it gives some great info on Enums: **[Java Enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/why-and-what-for-java-enum)**