# Java: how to create a variable that only allows 3 different values

Tags: java

How to create a variable that only allows 3 different values ? For example, the variable `color` can only take either one of the 3 values `{RED, BLACK, ORANGE}` and nothing else.

Obviously, I know that I can define `String color` , but is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: You are describing an enum.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are enums and why are they useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define an `enum`

```
public enum Color {
   RED, BLACK, ORANGE;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Color red = Color.RED;
```

You can define in or outside of the enclosing class.

If you wish to define it inside the class, the `enum` will be implicitly static (by default) and will be accessible it like this

```
SomeClass.Color red = SomeClass.Color.RED;
```

Comment: Where do I define this? Within or outside the class ?

Comment: How about testing for equality ? For example, I have `Color color = RED` , should I use `color.equals(RED)` or `color == RED` to test for equality ?

Comment: Use `==`. These are constants, so `==` should return true for `color == Color.RED`.

Comment: Yes, but in this way you don't have a real `java.awt.Color` information in your `enum`.

Comment: Who said that the `java.awt.Color` are needed? Read again the question

Comment: == and equals() are the same, per the implementation in the enum class: `   public final boolean equals(Object other) { 
        return this==other;
    }`

Comment: I don't know, because is neither told nor not been told.

Comment: Wait, how would the answer differ if I needed `java.awt.Color` ?

Comment: If you need only three constants from `java.awt.Color`, you can see the answer of @Guilio

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Enum.
It allows only to use specific Objects.

```
Enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };
Color var = Color.RED;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple way to define a `color` with no particular meaning:

```
public enum Color {
    RED, BLACK, ORANGE;
}
```

If you want to define a variable which can allows real `java.awt.Color`:

```
import java.awt.Color;


public enum MyColor
{
    RED (Color.RED),
    BLACK (Color.BLACK),
    ORANGE (Color.ORANGE);


    private Color value;

    private MyColor(Color value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Color getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum-variables/fields can hold `null` aswell, so you will have 4 possible values, BLACK,RED,ORANGE and `null`. Try to use `null` as BLACK.

```
enum Color {RED,ORANGE;
  static boolean isBlack(Color c){
    return c == null;
  }
  static boolean isRed(Color c){
    return c == RED;
  }
  static boolean isOrange(Color c){
    return c == ORANGE;
  }
};
```