# Porting C defines the Pythonic way

Tags: python, enums, constants

**tl;dr** What's a Pythonic (Py 3) way of specifying a large number of defined bit masks and constants? Use an Enum(s) or just have a load of consts as class variables? And the advantages/disadvantages?

**Background**

I'm porting C code to Python 3. In the C code there's a large number of defines which are used as bit masks:

```
#define ERR_1 = 0x8
#define ERR_2 = 0x2
#define ERR_4 = 0x100
...
```

I thought in Python a Pythonic way of having these would be by using an `Enum`, I came across `IntEnum` which means I don't have to use `.value` everywhere like I would with a normal `Enum`:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class Errors(IntEnum):
    BROKEN = 0x8
    FUBARED = 0x4
    GIVEUP = 0x7

print(0xFF & Errors.BROKEN)
```

but it's still more verbose than just having `print(0xFF & ERR_1)` which I could get if I had them all as consts.

Comment: If you want them less verbose you could name them `e1`, `e2` and `e4` (with the C codes) and use them as `Errors.e2`. Anyway, I think the enum is the way to go, and vervose is always good (specially if you plan to grow/mantain the software).

Answer (score 1):

I think using `enum` is more pythonic - there was a whole lot of effort put into creating that module, and not without a reason.

"Standard" way of things was using constants (like `ERR_1`) but this is ugly, buggy and really hard to mantain. This is why that module was developed.

Now that I've stated plain answer, I can also propose that you use both at the same time:

```
ERR_1 = 0x8
ERR_2 = 0x4
ERR_3 = 0x7

class Errors(IntEnum):
    BROKEN = ERR_1
    FUBARED = ERR_2
    GIVEUP = ERR_3

print(0xFF & Errors.BROKEN)
print(0xFF & ERR_1)
```

I think it's ugly, but you were torn between two options, so I wanted to show you how to make them one.

Also worth reading:

- [why use enum at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful) - it says "Java", but this is programming in general, not language-depentent issue
- [PEP about that module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) - you can see how many people thought that through and how thorough they were
- [not "which is more pythonic" but more "how to do it"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python) - with some arguments for using `enum` module
- [how were they thinking?](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/enum_creation.html) - "they" meaning "developers of that module"

Answer (score 1):

It all depends.

If the constants are logically *integers* (you do arithmetic, bitwise logic, etc. with them), they should be regular global variables.  Flag values fall here, as with the various flags for [`os.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open), but if you're just specifying a constant to indicate which operation to perform, an enum is more appropriate (or better yet, multiple driver functions).

Enumerated types are normally used when you have a (relatively) small set of values, and those values are mostly only compared to one another (e.g. with `if x is MyEnum.FIRST... elif x is MyEnum.SECOND` etc.).  In this case, you usually do not need `IntEnum` because you shouldn't be using `.value` very often to begin with.  Indeed, `IntEnum` is mostly a backwards-compatibility hack.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `Enum` is definitely the way to go, and you can even have the enum members at the module scope quite easily:

```
class Errors(IntEnum):
    BROKEN = 0x8
    FUBARED = 0x4
    GIVEUP = 0x7
globals().update(Errors.__members__)
```

so your comparison becomes:

```
print(0xFF & BROKEN)
```

About the only time it makes sense to not use `Enum` is when you have several names that aren't really duplicates but map to the same value, as the duplicate values will all map to the same name:

```
class Bad(Enum):
    BROKEN = 0x01
    MISSING = 0x01
    BLUE = 0x01
```

But if you have distinct names for unique values `Enum` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any reason to have them as part of a class.

`errors` module

```
# errors.py
BROKEN = 0x8
FUBARED = 0x4
GIVEUP = 0x7
```

`main` module

```
import errors

print(0xFF & errors.BROKEN)
```