# StringDef/IntDef vs Enum

Tags: android, performance

What is the difference between `@IntDef` and `Enum`? I can create `int` fields in `Enum`, so it will be also an instance with primitive data constants. Why Google recommends using `@IntDef`, can somebody explain? Does anyone of this two store its data in some specific way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360537/when-is-it-good-to-use-enum-in-android#comment52594240_32360537

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, saw lots of comments that it's premature optimization but I'm interested in the difference between `enum` and `@IntDef`. Trying to understand why Google recommends this and how does it work internally.

Comment: `@IntDef` is just an annotation, used by build tools to help make sure that you use `int` values with the proper meanings in the proper places. `enum` is an actual language construct in Java and Kotlin. The difference between `int` and `enum` is covered in advanced Java texts, plus a variety of of online resources, such as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9254637/115145).