# When and why is it useful to use Enumeration?

Tags: java, enumeration

When is it useful to work with the Java class [`Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) and why is it useful to work with it?

Comment: I think you can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful

Comment: Enumeration is useful if you are using Java 1.0 or 1.1 or an API which was written for these version.

Comment: when - last century :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) is largely obsolete. Per the Javadoc, it is an interface that *generates a series of elements, one at a time. Successive calls to the `nextElement` method return successive elements of the series.* It is the predecessor to [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) which (per the Javadoc)

> `Iterator` takes the place of [`Enumeration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) in the Java Collections Framework.

Comment: Iterator was added in Java 1.2  (1998) ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Which is also when Collection(s) were added. Apache Commons Collections provides [`EnumerationIterator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/EnumerationIterator.html) which can be used to make an `Enumeration` appear as an `Iterator`.

Comment: `Enumeration` is for code archaeologists