# How put options on a variable of an object?

Tags: java

I need make an objet (client) with this variables:

- Name
- Date
- Age
- Phone
- Type

But `Type` can only take 3 values: `Good`, `Fair`, `Poor`.

How you declare the variable `type`?

Comment: Take a look at `enum`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can define it as an enum to restrict the possible values to a small set:

```
enum Type {
    Good,
    Fair,
    Poor
}
```

And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful) for more background.

Comment: This can help too: [Stack Overflow documentation for Enums](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/155/enums#t=201610301920168839009)

Answer (score 1):

Create an [enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public enum Type {
    GOOD, FAIR, POOR 
}
```

Then you can declare `Type type;`.