# get or set a class value as strings

Tags: java

Remember in VB something like Struct.
I need to be able to set Class values like "Value1", "Value2" and so. then to be able to use an IF statement.

As for example

```
public class myClass{
value1 //string
value2 //string
value3 //string
}
```

And from any other class check it like

```
    if(myClass == myClass.value1){
    //anything
    }
```

And also assign the value

```
myClass = myClass.value2
```

Comment: You probably are looking for [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: yes, sorry i mismatch with Struct...

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, very thanks, now with the right search terms i found my needs. As you think, it's better to delete this question or i just leave it here?

Comment: Let's close it as a duplicate :)