# Understanding structure assigning values to Enums

Tags: c#

```
enum Days { Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat }; 

static void Main(string[] args) {
    int x = (int)Days.Tue;  
    Console.WriteLine(x);   //Outputs 2
}
```

I have two questions:

Q1. I don't understand why we need to assign int x to Enum as Enum have default values starting with index 0?

Q2. What is the real life example usage of Enum?

Comment: You don't assign `x` to an enum, you assign the enum value to `x`.

Comment: In many cases, you are not intereseted in the integer value of the enum. You would write `Days myDay = Days.Tue; Console.WriteLine(myDay); // Outputs Tue`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are enums and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful)

Comment: `What is the real life example usage of Enum?` In short: better readability like in your example for 'weekdays'.

Answer (score 0):

Enums enforce-ish* valid values.

```
enum Days { Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat }; 

static void Main(string[] args) {
    int weekday1 = (int)Days.Tue;  

    weeekday1 = 33; // What does this mean?

    Days weekday2 = Days.Tue;

    weekday2 = 33; // Compilation error. Good.
}
```

* = It's quite easy to make enum's value any int value, *if you really want to*.