# Different button actions from the same delegate method

Tags: swift

So I have a `FeatureTutorialDelegate` protocol with one `buttonPressed()` method. I have a `FeatureTutorialViewController` that functions as the delegate. A `PageViewController` calls these `FeatureTutorialViewController`  classes. The different pages have multiple buttons.

How do I make the different buttons do different things with the `buttonPressed()` method? I need the button to dismiss the tutorial, open other ViewControllers, etc, depending on which tutorial page the user taps the button on.

Comment: you need to pass variable in delegate method so when delegate is call check that variable and perform action accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an **enum** for the actions.

```
enum Action {
    case .dismiss
    case .open
}

protocol ADelegate {
    func buttonPressed(action: Action)
}

class A(){
    func navigate(){
        let b = B()
        b.delegate = self
    }
}

extension A: ADelegate {
    func buttonPressed(action: Action) {
        if  action == .dismiss {

        } else if action == .open{

        }
    }
}

class B {
    var delegate: ADelegate?

    func dismiss(){
        self.delegate?.buttonPressed(action: .dismiss)
    }

    func open(){
        self.delegate?.buttonPressed(action: .dismiss)
    }
}
```

Read this thread should you need to know why you should not use string as the other answer suggests.

[What are enums and why are they useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709175/what-are-enums-and-why-are-they-useful)

---

You may define multiple methods in the protocol. Doing so you avoid using if-else statement. It is cleaner.

```
protocol ADelegate {
    func dismiss()
    func open()
    func navigate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass variable in delegate method so when delegate is call check that variable and perform action accordingly.

```
protocol MoveFeatureTutorial {
    func buttonPressed(check: String)
}

var delegate: MoveFeatureTutorial
```

put below code in button action method

```
self.delegate?.buttonPressed(check: "For Button A")
self.delegate?.buttonPressed(check: "For Button B")
```

It's is the method that that protocol

```
func buttonPressed(check: String?) {
       if check == "For Button A" {
print(check)
} else if check == "For Button B" {
print(check)
} else {
print(check)
}
    }
```