# Java global methods without using static

Tags: java

Is there any way to create a method in Java that can be accessed from other classes without making the method static? As all the solutions I have seen online say to make the method static don't work for me as I am trying to reference a non-static variable from within the method. The variable I am referenceing is `this` (referring to the class it is in).

Comment: Why do you need `this` for a global method? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: If you need to reference `this`, it's not a global method, as it's bound to a single instance. If other code is to use that method, they'll need to create an instance (or perhaps use a shared instance).

Comment: How do you expect the other classes to get their value of `this` for your class?

Comment: Also consider using an `enum` to enforce the singleton property, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4709175/230513)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you need to reference `this`, it's not a global method, as it's bound to a single instance. If other code is to use that method, they'll need to create an instance.